# How To Show The First Page Number In The Default URL Using Pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, pagination

I'm using the CodeIgniter pagination library for building my page's links.
I defined a config array variable for my pagination as follows:

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = true;
```

All of my URLs look like `http://domain.com/class/function/#` (where # is the page number I'm on). However, the first page looks like `http://domain.com/class/function` and is missing the first page (#1).

Is there a build-in way in CodeIgniter of showing the first page if no page number is in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah use a route. In your `config/routes.php` file add this:

```
$route['class/function'] = 'class/function/1';
```

This way if the page number is missing it will assume the number `1` is in the URL, so it will show page #1